# How to change Android toolbar view?

Tags: android, toolbar, android-actionbar-compat, android-inflate

I'm working with the new android toolbar.

```
/* Jump into, after the user clicks on a listview item */
private void toogleToolbar() {
    if (isStandardToolbar)
        customToolbar();
    else
        originalToolbar();

    isStandardToolbar = !isStandardToolbar;
}

/* Called inside onCreate and if nothing was clicked */
private void originalToolbar() {
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
}


/* Called after an click event */
private void customToolbar() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    Toolbar toolbar = (ToolBar) inflater.inflate(R.layout.newtoolbar, null);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
}
```

It works so far, but now I want to change the toolbar view, after clicking on a list element.
That's my problem, because the last code snippet doesn't produce an exception or other issues, so it should be all ok. But I see only the "old" toolbar. I tried to set visibility to GONE or INVISIBLE to the old one, but it doesn't have any effect.

In my activity_main.xml, I include R.id.toolbar, but I think, the second code must overwrite the old one!?

EDIT:
AFAIK, the new toolbar should replace the old actionBar. Toolbar is used to place navigation or other, specific content. I my case, I want to create a small action menu, where the user can edit or delete a list item.

Comment: Add some code else. Whatever, I think you are not using correctly the call to Toolbar. Indeed, I bet for that. Try insert whole Toolbar and play with object.visibility(View.GONE) and View.VISIBLE.

Comment: I think the toolbar should be part of activity layout. In other case it would not show up. Do you want to have specific layout for toolbar based on some conditions?

Comment: Yes, I want to have a other layout on some conditions. I made my first post up.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to your question (maybe its too late...) but below is the code I used to make it :

`MainActivity.java` :

```
package fr.zwedge.sot;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.support.v7.app.*;
import android.support.v7.widget.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.View.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

boolean isStandardToolbar = true;
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = null, newToolbar = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    initToolbars();
    ((Button)toolbar.findViewById(R.id.tbt)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            toogleToolbar();
        }
    });
    ((Button)newToolbar.findViewById(R.id.tbt2)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            toogleToolbar();
        }
    });
}

/* Jump into, after the user clicks on a listview item */
private void toogleToolbar() {
    if (isStandardToolbar)
        customToolbar();
    else
        originalToolbar();
    isStandardToolbar = !isStandardToolbar;
}

private void initToolbars() {
    if (toolbar == null)
        toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (newToolbar == null)
        newToolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.newtoolbar);
}

/* Called inside onCreate and if nothing was clicked */
private void originalToolbar() {
    toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
}


/* Called after an click event */
private void customToolbar() {
    toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    setSupportActionBar(newToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
}
}
```

And here are the two toolbars in `main.xml` :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:titleTextColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:background="#FF008F12">
    <Button
        android:text="Bla bla bla"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/tbt" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/newtoolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:titleTextColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:background="#FF8F0800">
    <Button
        android:text="Change once again"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tbt2" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/text_view" />
```

Hope it helps you, Darkball60